# How to switch between first and third person perspective with one button in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I find myself switching back and forth between first and third person perspective frequently in World of Warcraft in order to take a good screenshot or to get a better view of a distant object. To switch to first person perspective I have to keep scrolling my scroll wheel to zoom the camera all the way in, and to switch back I have to reverse scroll all the way back.

I tried using the "Save View / Set View" function that is natively supported, but there are two problems:

1. "Save View" not only saves the camera distance, but also saves the camera angle. So while my camera is looking upward and I want to get a better view of a flying creature, pressing the "Set View" button will bring my camera to look forward.
2. Although the desired camera distance in 1st-person view is always 0, in 3-person view the desired camera distance varies. Selecting the saved 3-person view will force me to use the camera distance used when the view is saved.

Is there a solution that allows me to press one button to switch between first and third person perspective, like the 1st-/3rd-person buttons do in many third person shooters?

Comment: Specifically asking for add-ons will make this off-topic. Is there any way you could reword it so it's not a software recommendation?

Comment: @Vemonus Thank you Vemonus for your helpful edit. To answer your question: First of all I am not asking about addons specifically. I am asking for a specific solution (switching between 1st-/3rd-person view with one button), with addon being one possible solution.

Comment: @Vemonus Second, if an addon is proposed as a solution, it will be directly related to video gaming as it helps gamers perform a specific task in a game, so I believe that it is on-topic. That said, this is question that can be better discussed on meta. There are already some interesting discussions like https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/what-to-do-with-add-on-questions/

Comment: it's okay to ask for a solution and have an add on be the solution. Specifically asking for software recommendations is a reason to vote to close. Basically, just reword your question to remove the recommendation request and it'll be all good!

Comment: @Vemonus Thank you again for your reply. The reason I list addon explicitly in my question is due to the exhaustive nature of my question. World of Warcraft's TOC permits macros and addons as the only two options that can help users achieve functions not natively supported in the game. Since my research indicates that a solution is unlikely to be achieved natively, it is foreseeable that a solution will be either a macro or an addon.

Comment: @Vemonus Regarding the software recommendation concern you raised. I think the rationale behind not allowing software recommendations is due to their open-ended nature. In my case since there is a definitive criteria (whether or not they can perform one specific task), what I am asking for is not really a "recommendation", but a "solution".

Comment: I think you're missing my point. The reason recommendation requests aren't on-topic aren't due to the publisher of a game not approving of them. It's due to that open-ended nature. An add on that fixes one issue may bring others into play or may include other unnecessary features. Multiple add ons may apply to the situation. It also bars answers that aren't just add on recommendations. By removing the add on specification, you would get answers that may or may not include an add on, but (should) solve your problem. The fix isn't necessarily an add on, so it's not necessary to ask 4 1

Comment: For instance, you asked for add ons, but the first answer to appear proposes a solution that's *not* an add on, which proves my point about it being unnecessary to specifically ask for an add on.

Comment: @Vemonus Haha you are right. That answer is a disproof to what I just said. I will edit my answer as you instructed.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an option due to the resulting camera angle you mentioned, but a macro could do the trick. `/run if 1st == 1 then SetView(1); 1st = 0; else 1st = 1; SaveView(1); CameraZoomIn(30) end` (I'm not on my WoW PC, so I can't test it, but I'll happily post it as answer, if it does.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but...

The <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys zoom between 5 different fixed presets, with <kbd>Home</kbd> generally zooming in and <kbd>End</kbd> generally zooming out.

These presets are:

1. First Person View
2. Third Person View short distance, from directly behind. This is the default.
3. Third Person View short distance, 45 degree angle.
4. Third Person View far distance, 45 degree angle.
5. Third Person View far distance, from directly behind.

Comment: Thank you. This poses the same problem as user-definied view sets in that it will force the camera into a pre-defined angle. Nonetheless, when I do want look afront in 1st-person view (which happens frequently when I want to look at an NPC more closely), this will definitely be faster than scrolling my scroll wheel.